# Is it Simple past, Past Subjunctive, or what?

Tags: past-tense, conditional-constructions

In this past sentence:

> I **wanted** to have a little time to myself before everybody else **woke up** at 7:00 am

Is "woke up" being used as simple past, past subjunctive, conditional or what? If it's in simple past, how could it be simple past if it hasn't happened yet? It might never happen, it's hypothetical.

Comment: Think of it as a backshift of *I **want** to have a little time ... before everybody **wakes** up* -- same tense as the main clause, but with a later time reference.

Comment: What makes you think it's a conditional?  There is nothing predicated on whether or not everyone else will wake up at 7.

Comment: @Andrew Maybe a subjunctive?

Comment: Are you thinking of phrases from 19th and 18th century English where the subjunctive is used with **ere** and **before**, as in **ere|before he see** ?

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo after taking a look at the "modern" subjunctive form, it's written exactly the same way as the simple past. I'm considering to edit the question asking if it is a subjunctive past tense or a simple past.

Comment: It's a time clause with a conjunction "before".

Comment: @V.V. But how "woke up" can be something that already happened if it is hypothetical.

Comment: @Luciano  That's kind of my point.  "Wanted" is past tense, so this is an event that already happened.  Everyone else **woke up** at 7 (that morning in the past), but before then, I had some time to myself.  There is no hypothetical or conditional there.